# Ways to create clients of soap web services

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

I started recently to develop some SOAP and REST web services. In SOAP web services, I found out that I must develop a client first so I can consume the service.

I would like to know the different ways to develop a client for a web service.

I see the ways of developing a clients for SOAP web services are independent of the web service implementation (CXF, AXIS, JAXB). For example, a way to create a client is using the `wsimport` command line that generates a client code by giving the WSDL as an argument.

What about other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a SOAP web service you have to send it a properly formatted SOAP message that respects the service's contract. That's it!

So basically to create a client you just need to build that XML message, for example, given [this service](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx), you can do the following (I'm assuming Java since you tagged the question like that - but it applies to any programming language):

**1)** use string concatenation (this is as basic as you can get):

```
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 2;
String myMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
  + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
  + "  <soap:Body>"
  + "    <Add xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
  + "      <intA>" + number1 + "</intA>"
  + "      <intB>" + number2 + "</intB>"
  + "    </Add>"
  + "  </soap:Body>"
  + "</soap:Envelope>";
```

then do a (basic) [POST that to the service](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) taking care to provide it with the required HTTP headers (like `SOAPAction`, etc).

**2)** manually build an XML document to send to the service, something like [using SAAJ](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhg.html) for example.

**3)** use the [service WSDL](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL) and feed it to a tool (wsimport, wsdl2java, etc) from some framework/library (JAX-WS, Axis2, CXF, etc) to get back a client that abstracts the call to a simple method invocation taking Java objects and returning Java objects.

**4)** Any other method you can think of to create the SOAP message and send it as a POST request (I see you tagged the question JAXB, that will do too...).

Calling a SOAP web service is so common these days that nobody bothers to spend time building a client when there are tools for almost every language to generate one from the WSDL. It's boilerplate code.

People just want a client, to shove it in the project, to use it, and to move on to doing more important stuff in their application. That's why most go for point 3).

> I see the ways of developing a clients for SOAP web services are independent of the web service implementation

Yes, you can have a service in a programming language/technology stack and the client in another. The SOAP protocol is the common denominator. Respect the protocol and service contract and the service can work with any client.